# Docker-Compose & Ubuntu : Cannot Access Host Internet

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Using docker-compose I cannot access the host internet access.

Docker can access the network because it pulls down the correct image but the container fails when running apt-get:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

This has worked on multiple Ubuntu instances, they were all using DHCP, this time it's within the company network with manual networking setup.

It's my understanding that docker-compose should use the host network.

I have not added any manual networks in my yaml. All defaults.

Comment: try adding `network_mode: host` as a quick fix

Comment: Unfortunately didn't do the trick, or network_mode: bridge :(

Comment: Do you have a proxy server on your company network?

Comment: I am unsure of the network setup (until tomorrow), but that is a huge possibility.

Comment: Is this a DNS issue from inside the container?

Comment: Looks like a network issue as any containers can't ping 8.8.8, but they pull down from docker.io fine.